How should I display panorama image in React Native?
How should I go about showing a panorama image in RN? What library do you suggest I use? The only ones I've found so far are outdated.
I've already tried using react-native-panorama-view but the latest version seems to not work anymore. What are other alternatives to this?

What would be the aspect ratio of the panorama image you are trying to display? In general, sometimes above 2:1 ratio is considered as panorama. Why don't you try  with height and width in that proportionate with resizeMode as either contain or stretch.

Hi! Thanks for replying! I wanna achieve the same effect as Facebook's 360 image where you can tilt your camera to look around the photo. Is there a library I can use for that?

I decided to use expo-three which is a utility for using three.js library in expo apps.
https://github.com/expo/expo-three
Then I just copied example from three examples repo
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/webgl_panorama_equirectangular.html
and translated it into expo world.
Both expo-three and three.js are good, maintained libraries and I believe they will not stop working in the near future.
